# Canvas rotate image which depicts an angled ellipse

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I have an image in my canvas and am trying to rotate it in an unusual way. I have my image rotating but on the wrong origin point.

I want to rotate the image in such a way that the ellipse is shown to be rotating from it's origin point rather than the image itself rotating. There for ultimately the ellipse would be stationary in the canvas and simply rotating.

This is my current code:

```
var canvas      = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx         = canvas.getContext('2d');

var angle;
var toRads      = Math.PI/180;  
var start       = new Date().getTime();
var rotation    = 15;


function draw(){
    var x         = canvas.width/2 - img.width/2;
    var y         = canvas.height/2 - img.height/2;
    var deltaTime = new Date().getTime() - start;

        start     = new Date().getTime();
        angle     = (angle || 0) + (deltaTime/1000 * rotation);

    if(angle > 360){angle = 0;}

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(x,y);
        ctx.rotate(angle * toRads);
        ctx.drawImage(img,20,20);
        ctx.restore();    

    setTimeout(draw,1);
}
```

I was wondering if this can be done in 2D or is it only possible via 3D such as webGL stuff?

I created a jsfiddle of what I have got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/hc0p5e06/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the transformations are important. You are missing a translation to place the origin of the circle at the right point (assuming you want the center)

```
   var w = img.width;  // get the image width and height
   var h = img.height;
   ctx.translate(x,y);
   ctx.rotate(angle * toRads);
   ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,w,h,-w/2,-h/2,w,h); // draw the image translated half
                                             // its size up and left in the new
                                             // coordinate space
```

Comment: By center do you mean image or circle?

Comment: You can make the center where ever you want it. The 6 & 7th arguments of drawImage should be the negative of the location on (or off)  the image you want to rotate around.

Comment: But the issue is, the ellipse is not a perfect circle so the origin will differ if i want just that to spin. If you imagine the ellipse as just a circle at an angle, and you want it to rotate like a wheel,  I don't fully get how that would be done.

Comment: If you are after a rolling ellipse you will have to change the origin in relation to the angle . Something like `var yOff = (Math.cos(angle*2)*((w-h)/2))/2;` then add that to the first translate y coord. but the rolling ellipse has an axle offset from the point of ground contact, on a moving car the wheel's (ellipse's) rotation speed must vary for the car to maintain constant speed. Try searching "rolling ellipse"